# Software to add notifications to CD

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm perhaps looking for an advanced third party CD burning piece of software.  What I'm actually looking for is some software that allows me to add a dialog box/notification that pops up when a user reads a CD.  The dialog box/notification contains custom text.

(The reason I'm looking for this if I've got a PPT show that will only work properly on Office 2010 and 2013, so I want a notification to pop up that tells the user they need to have that installed for the PPT to work properly).

Specifications:

- Freeware/shareware
- Works on Windows 7

Comment: I doubt there will be such a thing generating a popup on file-access. But if it is sufficient to display the hint whenever the medium is *mounted* (i.e. put into the drive), there's the [`autorun.inf`](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000670.htm) which could be used for it. For multi-platform solutions, this file has counter-parts, like `autorun.sh` for Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for that.  I wasn't too sure if such a thing existed, but what you suggested will be fine (although not software :P)

Comment: As it will be fine, I've made it an answer for you to accept – including more details, to bring you a little closer to what you originally asked :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a "pop-up" generated interactively whenever a certain file is accessed, it requires some process running in the background monitoring all file-accesses. While I've never heard about anything *exactly* like you've described, I at least can suggest you something "close":

There are files you can put into the root directory of a "changeable medium" such as CD, DVD, BD, or even USB-Stick, which describe what should happen whenever that medium is "mounted" (i.e. inserted into the drive/USB-port and made ready-to-use). For Windows systems, that's [`autorun.inf`](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000670.htm) (just follow the link for a how-to), and a similar counter-part for Unix/Linux systems (plus probably Macs) would be the `autorun.sh`. That way you couldn't only have an ordinary "pop-up" opening, but run any program you've stored on that medium. Or, probably better fitting for your use-case: Have the default browser opening an HTML file stored on it, with detailed description – and optionally links to more pages, even listing your Office files with explanations along, where again we reach the point we're started at: connecting those files with information relevant for them.

Comment: +1 but keep in mind that some users like me disable the Autorun functionality in Windows (partly because you can put some viruses in autorun just as well as your notification popup -> [Disable AutoRun to Stop 50% of Windows Malware Threats](http://lifehacker.com/5858703/disable-autorun-to-stop-50-of-windows-malware-threats))

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that for sure. To be honest, I'd have it disabled as well would I run Windows. Good point!